# Mail merge - Multiple Rows in base data need to be shown together

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge

I've an Excel spreadsheet with the base data for a Word Mailmerge.

Each policy is on a different line, however a client may have four lines.
I want one letter to be sent to a client based on all of their policies in the data source. Is this possible?

Data contains:
ID, Name, Address, Policy, Underwriter

Mailmerge has a table and in the table if the client has one row I want it to show only that one row, if they have four rows, I want it to show all four, for example.
I can do it if all the data appears on one row but not if it's on multiple.

Comment: This is often known as a one-many Mailmerge in Word, and I suggest you search for that term as there are several approaches to solutions out there (and you may find coverage of some of them in here and/or superuser.com as well).

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/38721-microsoft-word-catalogue-directory-mailmerge-tutorial.html